# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from: objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSpamSignal.o)

Tags: ios, google-plus-signin

Hello I have a project that some one has developed. It has G+, FB integration. When I get the project and try to run it, it gives me this error. How I can solve this? Please help me.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSpamSignal.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please give more infos about how you're running it, Xcode version, targeted platform, device or simulator used ?

Comment: Xcode is 6.3, deployment target 8.3, Required device capabilities - armv 7

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Undefined symbols means usually that you are missing an import statement.
Looks like you are using 
[CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/) is part of CoreMotion, so you might need to :

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```

And verify that you have added `CoreMotion` to your project

Comment: No.  That would be a compile error.  The OP needs to link against `CoreMotion.framework`.

Answer (score 3):

As CMMotionManager is part of CoreMotion framework, simply include the framework in your build in Xcode in "target"'s Build Phases: "link with": add "+" "CoreMotion.framework"

Answer (score 1):

I managed to invoke this unholy error by simply adding the `.h` and `.m` files to the project.

I fixed this by removing them, and then right-clicking on the project, clicking New File, and choosing a new iOS Cocoa Touch class.

After that, I copied the relevant code into the respective `.h` and `.m` files. Doing it this way properly links the files

Answer (score 1):

CMMotionManager is part of CoreMotion.framework. 
In Xcode 11.3, TARGETS > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content > click the add button '+', add CoreMotion.framework.  
The picture is in the below.

[image]

Comment: I LOVE YOU <3333333333

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using GooglePlus SDK and the SDK is not supporting arm64 architecture. You need an updated SDK that supports arm64 architecture. Make sure you have latest copy.